# How to set hidden field same as shown field based on dropdown menu Asp MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem because hidden fields are null when I select `Business` carrier type.

I want `Individual` filed filled out same as `Business`
OR get the same value if the m.somthing is same between `individual` and `business`.

**I have cshtml as following:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CarrierType, ViewBag.CarrierTypeList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle", id = "CarrierType" })
    </div>
</div>
<!--Individual-->
<div id="Individual">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DriverLicenseNumber, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Driver's License Number", required = "required", tabindex = 15 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DriverLicenseNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehicleRegNumber, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Vehicle Registration Number", required = "required", tabindex = 16 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VehicleRegNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehiclePlateNumber, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Vehicle Plate Number", required = "required", tabindex = 17 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VehiclePlateNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VecInsNum, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Vehicle Isurance Number", required = "required", tabindex = 18 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VecInsNum, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FleetType, ViewBag.NCFleetTypeList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-primary  dropdown-toggle" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Business-->
<div id="Business">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DriverLicenseNumber, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Driver's License Number", required = "required", tabindex = 15 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DriverLicenseNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehicleRegNumber, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Vehicle Registration Number", required = "required", tabindex = 16 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VehicleRegNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VehiclePlateNumber, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Vehicle Plate Number", required = "required", tabindex = 17 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VehiclePlateNumber, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VecInsNum, new { @class = "form-control ", placeholder = "Vehicle Isurance Number", required = "required", tabindex = 18 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.VecInsNum, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FleetType, ViewBag.CFleetTypeList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "btn btn-primary  dropdown-toggle" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And below JS works perfect what I desired:**

```
function hideOnLoadCarrierType() {
    $('#Individual').hide();
    $('#Business').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    hideOnLoadCarrierType();
    $('#CarrierType').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == '1') {
            $('#Individual').show();
            $('#Business').hide();
            } else if (value == '2') {
                $('#Individual').hide();
                $('#Business').show();
            } else {
                hideOnLoadCarrierType();
            }
        });
    });
```

But the problem is; When I filled out business info and try register (all fields are `required` in model), gives me error because `Individual` field not set.

Can you help me out?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try writing an event handler for the form and performing any logic you need right before the form is submitted. In the snippet below, I'm filling up the empty fields in `Individuals` with their `Business` counterpart when the form is submitted:

```
// Assuming the form has a submit button with id = "submit-btn"
$('#submit-btn').on('click', function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var businessDiv = form.find('#Business');
    // Assuming this is only required when Business is selected
    if(businessDiv.is(':visible')) {
        var individual = form.find('#Individual input:text');
        var business = businessDiv.find('input:text');
        for(var i = 0; i < individual.length; ++i) {
            // Perform the required logic here. 
            // I'm just forcing all empty fields in individuals to
            // their business counterpart
            if(individual[i].value === "") {
                individual[i].value = business[i].value;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo**
Here is a live demo of the code with a rough sketch of what the rendered HTML should look like:
http://www.bootply.com/ZHVTKLJNj3

Comment: Thank You!!! You are the Best!
Can I ask one more question?
How can I set TextBoxtFor value with string "N/A", when a user click the link text click in the view  
Below is my code:
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReferralId, new { @class = "form-control", id="CheckReferralId", placeholder = "Referral ID (Inviter)", required = "required", tabindex = 0 })
                        <small>If you do not have Referral ID, <a href="#">click</a></small>`

Comment: Here is link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653569/how-to-set-text-box-for-based-on-click-behavior-asp-mvc)

Thank you again!

Comment: @SeongKim You bet. feel free to mark the answer as accepted or upvote if the posts were useful.