# How to set text box for based on click behavior ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

How can I set `TextBoxtFor` value with string "`N/A`", when a user click the link text `click` in the view

Below is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReferralId, new { @class = "form-control", id="CheckReferralId", placeholder = "Referral ID (Inviter)", required = "required", tabindex = 0 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReferralId, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <small>If you do not have Referral ID, <a href="#">click</a></small>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to the referral id anchors, say `class="no-referral-link"` and then the following jQuery should do the trick

**HTML**

```
<small>If you do not have Referral ID, <a href="#" class="no-referral-link">click</a></small>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.no-referral-link').click(function(e) {
  $('#CheckReferralId').val('N/A');
});
```

Comment: I have one last question.. I am so sorry..
I think this problem you can solve for me.
Thanks in advance! [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656157/select-list-item-value-does-not-working-with-javascript-asp-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by Javascript. Add onclick event to your  tag

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"> -- So when you click the below function will set value 'N/A' to your textbox

function myFucntion(){
$('#CheckReferralId').val('N/A'); -- this is easy since you use ID for your element
}
```